# How to disable profile name in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to get rid of the little name icon in the upper right. It wasn't there until a few updates ago. I tried disabling avatar/new profile management stuff in `chrome://flags`, but that didn't work. The settings are saved on Disabled but the profile name doesn't go away. Any help?

Thanks in advance. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, and my Chrome version is 44.0.2403.130.

Comment: I did, no dice. Been trying at this for like a week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **Chrome 44 and higher**:

`chrome://flags/#enable-new-profile-management` no longer works, and probably [won't be](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=496829) fixed in future too. But there is workaround:

If you want a temporary solutions (that works only for a 'session', you can start chrome from terminal with the `--disable-new-avatar-menu` flag as in:

```
google-chrome --disable-new-avatar-menu
```

If you want a permanent solution:

1. Edit your Chrome `.desktop` and add the parameter `--disable-new-avatar-menu`. So:

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
   ```

   and edit the `Exec` line as follows:

   ```
   Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --disable-new-avatar-menu %U
   ```

   My `.desktop` file for chrome looks like this:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Google Chrome
   GenericName=Web Browser
   Comment=Access the Internet
   Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --disable-new-avatar-menu %U
   Terminal=false
   Icon=google-chrome
   Type=Application
   Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
   MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;image/webp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/$
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;NewIncognito

   [NewWindow Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Window
   Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [NewIncognito Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Incognito Window
   Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
2. Restart Chrome

   [image]

For **Chrome 43 and lower**:

1. Copy/paste the following into the omnibox: `chrome://flags/#enable-new-avatar-menu`
2. Set the value to "Disabled"
3. Restart Chrome

Comment: The temporary fix worked, the long term one did not. I checked the document and the new line did save (I added it at the very end). I did use gedit instead of nano, but I don't believe that should change anything? Rebooted too. No dice. (When just using Chrome from the side launcher)

Comment: It should not be added at the end. Add it as the 6th line. I've included my `.desktop` file, if it helps. Shouldn't matter which text editor you use (as long as you've the write permission to the file)

Comment: It actually wasn't the 6th line either, but I found it eventually. Works now. Thank you so much! This has actually been a great learning experience besides just solving the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I have one other unrelated question though, you seem like someone who knows stuff and I didn't get an answer last time I asked it. Every time I open Chrome, the window opens in a position slightly lower than the last each time. It's extremely annoying, and happens even though I have windows set to open center, and every other application opens center consistently. This happens with both Chrome and Chromium. Any idea what this is or how to fix it? If not that's fine. Sorry to waste your time further.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to avoid this for as long as I could and now I gave up. There is one thing you can do. Click on the name button and select "Switch person" and then select "Browse as guest". In that way your chrome will not synchronize setting over all computers.

Comment: My favorites and frequently visited sites and passwords and whatnot are pretty important to me. I tried this but it's tough to work without them.